# Magento - No Transactional Emails in fresh install of 1.7.0.2 CE

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

There are no Transactional emails in 'System > Transactional EMails' in a fresh install, how do I import them or get them in the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can edit from admin just go to

```
System > Transactional Emails >
```

and click  ‘Add new template’

from first drop you can select template type

Also if please check directory of your local machine

```
 app\locale\en_US\template\email
```

check above directory is html file is exist or not.

hope this will sure help u,

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesnot contain any default Transaction Email entries by default.
It uses the template from

```
app\locale\[language code]\template\email
```

If one is not satisfied with default templates he/she can edit it by going in

```
System > Transactional Emails
```

and click 'Add New Template'